# How to set a "Profile Picture" in Roundcube Webmail

Tags: email, email-address, webmail, email-accounts

How do I set a profile picture for a custom email address, i. e., a picture that appears beside the subject on sites like Gmail. For example, if an image is not set, the picture shows the first letter of the name of the sender in Gmail, using Roundcube?

Comment: I believe that if you create a Google account using the custom email address, then go to your Google account settings and upload a profile picture there, then it will start appearing in other Google users' Gmail inboxes. I'm not entirely sure though. For other clients, I wonder if it would help to also create a [gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/).

Answer (score 3):

The profile image (or avatar) shown besides each sender's email is a function of the email client you are using.

GMail uses Google accounts for profile images for emails sent from other GMail users, or creates default images based on the name for other addresses.

Other email clients use different methods to suggest an image to associate with received emails.

Sources:

- https://www.roundcubeforum.net/index.php?topic=24320.0
- https://utechpia.com/how-to-add-an-email-profile-picture-to-any-domain-email-address/
- https://www.roundcubeforum.net/index.php?topic=28824.0

A couple of 3rd party plugins for RoundeCube are [RoundCube Gravitar](https://github.com/prodrigestivill/roundcube-gravatar) or [RoundCube Banner Warn](https://github.com/pulsejet/banner-warn), on GitHub.

When **sending** emails it's possible to use an HTML signature to embed a image that will be visible as your avatar in the recipient's email client, see here for instructions: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/html-signature-image/, https://www.siteground.com/kb/add-image-signature-roundcube-webmail-client/ or https://support.newoldstamp.com/en/articles/4755050-how-to-add-a-signature-to-roundcube

- Set your email composer to use HTML by default
- Add an image to your signature file: `<img src="logo.png">`.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got a very useful tutorial on Google Forum.

According to the reply, simply follow the following steps to get your profile image while sending emails:

1. Create a Google+ file with the address you wish to have a profile image (yes, you may create an account with yourname@yourdomain.com).
2. Enjoy the joy sending emails/newsletters. :)

Comment: It doesnt work for me.
I made the Google+ and send email to gmail,
after to yahoo... and it doesnt work.

Comment: It also makes no sense to me.