# How do I set a profile picture in RoundCube?

Tags: webmail

Given that Google+ is no longer a thing the answer suggested here is incorrect:

[How to set a "Profile Picture" in Roundcube Webmail](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95030/how-to-set-a-profile-picture-in-roundcube-webmail)

Comment: Hi Keith, welcome to Webmasters Stack Exchange. To keep things tidy around here, I need to mark this as a duplicate. If you're interested in that specific question, you can click the follow button on it to receive notifications of new answers. Once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you can [upvote](/help/privileges/vote-up) it, or create a [bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) to attract more attention to it.

Comment: I do have an inkling of an idea though, which I also posted as a comment on the other post: I believe that if you create a Google account using your custom email address, then go to your Google account settings and upload a profile picture there, then it will start appearing in other Google users' Gmail inboxes. I'm not entirely sure though. For other clients, I wonder if it would help to also create a [gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/).

Comment: Check [this Google support article](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27441?hl=en#existingemail), and scroll down to where it says "Use an existing email address". Basically, during the account creation process you will need to click "Use my current email address instead."

Comment: Thank you @MaximillianLaumeister! You are very kind.

Comment: If you have your own domain, then the favicon from there gets used in some email clients.

Comment: thanks @RohitGupta